# Who makes the X-uniforms?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In the comics, who makes the uniforms for the X-men? I've seen several references to the X-men designing/choosing their own costumes, but who actually sews them? Who is the X-tailor?

Comment: Obviously not [Edna Mode](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Edna_Mode) *("No [capes](http://static8.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_small/14/148344/3409899-tormenta3tb.jpg)!")*

Comment: There's an X-person who's power is sewing. :-D

Comment: The Home-X class students?

Comment: X-Barneys. They have a wide selection.

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Uniforms

Comment: Lin k never says who actually makes the uniforms

Comment: The Koenig brothers

Comment: Former Alpha Flight villain Scramble the Mixed-Up Man was a mutant who could mold and transmute flesh. If it worked on leather...

Answer (score 3):

In [X-Force Vol.1 #19](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Force_Vol_1_19) Boom-Boom uses a "Shi'ar Clothes Synthesizer." It appears to work like a replicator and a holodeck from Star Trek, allowing the user to program the computer to create costumes instantaneously on their bodies. The Synthesizer is in the mansion.

[image]

Comment: Do they use it often? I assume this is not a tool they use day-to-day.

Comment: I never saw it used again.